# How can I get table creation scripts on teradata with jdbc?

Tags: jdbc, metadata, resultset, teradata

I want to get table creation script on teradata with jdbc.
I used this code which I found it on stackoverflow :

```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( 1024 );
                if ( columnCount > 0 ) { 
                    sb.append( "Create table ").append( rsmd.getTableName( 1 )  ).append( " ( " );
                }
                for ( int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i ++ ) {
                    if ( i > 1 ) sb.append( ", " );
                    String columnName = rsmd.getColumnLabel( i );
                    String columnType = rsmd.getColumnTypeName( i );

                    sb.append( columnName ).append( " " ).append( columnType );

                    int precision = rsmd_ddl.getPrecision( i );
                    if ( precision != 0 ) {
                        sb.append( "( " ).append( precision  ).append( " )" );
                    }
                } // for columns
                sb.append( " ) " );
```

But the problem is : when the type is `VARCHAR` the precision is `0` but in teradata the column is `VARCHAR(100)` but how can I find `100` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

getPrecision is for Decimals, you should use getColumnDisplaySize for chars.

There are lots of samples in the Teradata JDBC reference:
http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/frameset.html

Sample T20100JD shows how to ectract metadata.

Answer (score 2):

> getPrecision is for Decimals, you should use getColumnDisplaySize for chars

Teradata has a flaw/bug in their JDBC driver implementation in that they are not properly implementing the contract of the interface.

The Java API documentation for interface java.sql.ResultSetMetaData explicitly defines the expected behavior for the getPrecision() method with different datatypes:

```
int getPrecision(int column)
                 throws SQLException

Get the designated column's specified column size. 
For numeric data, this is the maximum precision. 
For character data, this is the length in characters. 
...
```

The Teradata JDBC driver incorrectly returns 0 when getPrecision() is called for a VARCHAR column. Therefore, when working with Teradata JDBC one must use getColumnDisplaySize().